# Question about Ordering with the Multinomial Coefficient.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was studying Probability and came across a problem regarding Ordering and Multinomial Coefficient.

From my understanding of the Multinomial Coefficient, $\binom{n}{n_1, n_2,...,n_r }$ equals to the number of ways to divide $n$ into $r$ distinct groups, and that the order of the groups do not matter.

Now I face the problem in this question:

> A football team consists of 20 offensive and 20 defensive players. The players are to
> be paired in groups of 2 for the purpose of determining roommates. If the pairing is
> done at random, what is the number of ways of forming pairs such that there are no offensive–defensive room-mate pairs?

The solution is: $\frac{40!}{2^{20}(20)!}$ ways.

I don't understand why do we divide by $20!$.

I am currently thinking in the direction about Permutation and Combination, where for $n$ distinct object, they differ by a factor of $r!$. In that case, what "order" are we dividing away by the $20!$?

Comment: I think this question is ambiguous; it's not clear whether the pairs themselves are to be regarded as ordered or unordered (which is where the $20!$ comes from). When you say "the order of the groups do not matter" in your second paragraph you mean that you can freely permute the $n_i$. But the groups themselves come in an order, namely $n_1$, then $n_2$, then etc. If each $n_i$ is the same then you can further consider dividing out by permutations of the groups themselves.

Comment: Note that $40!/(2^{20}20!)$ is the **total** number of ways to pair up the $40$ players. You place them in a line in $40!$ ways, then pair up adjacent people. Within each adjacent pair, order does not matter, so you divide by $2^{20}$. The order of the pairs themselves does not matter, so you divide by $20!$. However, there is a much smaller number for the number of ways to pair of the players where offensive players must pair with offensive players.

Comment: The answer given by the book's solution can be said to describe the number of ways of having these players room together where each player is distinct and the only pieces of information we care about are who rooms with who but we do not care about who gets top-bunk versus bottom-bunk and we do not care about their room#.  The division by $2^{20}$ is how we ignore top-bunk vs bottom-bunk (*i.e. order within the groups irrelevant*) and the division by $20!$ is how we ignore room# assignments (*i.e. labeling of the groups is irrelevant*)

Comment: If you prefer to avoid a "division by symmetry" argument, consider lining up your players in some canonical order (*e.g. name*).  For the first person in line, choose a corresponding partner from those remaining to room with them and remove these two from the line.  Continue in this process, getting a total of $39\times 37\times 35\times \cdots \times 1 = 39!!$ using double-factorial notation.  As alluded to earlier, this was the total amount if we did not care about defensive/offensive lineups.  The answer where we do care should be $19!!\times 19!!$

Comment: The previous comments explain the given solution.  As you can see, this particular problem does **not** lend itself to using the multinomial coefficient to construct the solution.

Comment: The question has another serious defect. Quoting (with emphasis mine), it reads "**If the pairing is done at random**,...  number of ways ... there are no offensive–defensive room-mate pairs? " With random pairing, this number could range from zero pairs to all pairs !